# Magento 2 ui/form/field template Error since Upgrade from 2.3.7 to 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.4, uicomponent

since I updated from Magento 2.3.7 to 2.4.5-p1 I'm getting some errors with some **xml** layouts.

On one of my XML files where I had
`<item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>`
now is throwing an error `[ERROR] Failed to load the "ui/form/field" template requested by`.

```
<item name="name" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">XXX</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">My_Module/element/input</item>
    </item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">XXX.name</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First name</item>
    <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
    <item name="autocomplete" xsi:type="string">given-name</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">XXX</item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

This was working before the upgrade so I can imagine there's something I'm missing with +2.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing an issue with the XML file layout structure.

To resolve this, please make sure as of Magento 2.4.5, the XML structure is quite strictly identified:

Steps to reproduce:

- The component path to HTML is correct, i.e., **The path to the
  component's .html template.** ui/form/field exists.
- Every tag has an open and closed tag.
- As of Magento 2.4.5, HTML tags must have nested and closed properly
  to meet standards in JQuery 3.5.x for non-void elements, including
  custom elements.
- Please check your custom HTML element template **My_Module/element/input**
  contains proper HTML with open and closed tags to match the standards.

As in the latest release, the Magento KO engine is quite strict and complex with these things.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've reviewed all the checkpoints and it's still not working.
I've tried creating a custom template with the content of the ui/form/fields and then it works...

Comment: Perfect that's good to know you have successfully figured it out. Please post your answer for useful to others.

Comment: But that's not a solution, because it means that I cannot use the ui/form/field from de Magento 2 core. I want to continue using the resources that Magento give.

Comment: No you can use the resources that Magento give. But you are focusing on custom so you need to follow the extended functionality that Magento provides. Please have a look into it: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

Answer (score 1):

There are some custom templates (*.html) with a closing ko tag that had no opening tag or vice versa.

As of Magento 2.4.4 HTML tags must have nested and closed properly to meet standards in JQuery 3.5.x for non-void elements including custom elements.

So you have to make sure all *.html has the correct open/close tags.

Comment: I've reviewed all the *.html files on that module and only one extra closing tag and it's still not working. Anyway, I've tried (just to test) to create a custom .html with the content of the 'ui/form/field' on my module and it doesn't shows the error...
Thank you for your answer

Comment: Did you remove `pub/static/frontend` and `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend` and re-deploy static content?

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and still not working. Very strange :(